# Visual Studio Autocomplete for Html Helpers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, intellisense

When writing Html helper elements in Razor such as:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyProperty, new { @class="col-sm-2 control-label" })
```

Or

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyProperty, new { @class="form-control", placeholder="Property" })
```

Visual studio is converting the "new {" to "new object {", however this is invalid.  Why does intellisense do this?  Am I missing something?

Comment: It does it to me too. I just delete the `object` part and continue on with my day.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it's because of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703538%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) specific overload signature:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

After all, `htmlAttributes` has to have *some* kind of type declaration, and `Object` was the lowest common denominator they picked, since `dynamic` wasn't available when these methods were originally written.

It's kind of annoying, for sure- but Intellisense is just doing its job :)